# Is there a setting in Visual Studio 2010 to stop the 'Add New Item' wizard from using server-side code for web forms?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, settings, webforms

I hate *hate* ***HATE*** that Visual Studio creates .aspx.cs and aspx.designer.cs files every time I add a new .aspx page to my project.

I've searched high and low.  How do I turn this off?

There used to be a little checkbox right on the wizard that allowed you to say whether you wanted server-side code pages or not.  VS 2010 appears to have removed it.

Comment: Why do you hate this so much? where do you put your code?

Comment: Inline, of course.  Same as MVC views.  Code behind pages are so 2003/2005.

Comment: ok if you say so. if you are so against them and mention MVC, then why not just move to MVC? you are doing something wrong BIG TIME if you are against .aspx.cs and the designer pages!

Comment: I do use MVC. But there are projects I work on that haven't been upgraded because it would take too much time/money.  You can't just snap your fingers and move a large ASP.NET web app project to MVC.  Being against .aspx.cs and designer pages isn't wrong at all.  To the contrary, it is far more architecturally sound to write clean in-line page code.  The MS .NET team has said this themselves.  In fact, MVC attempted to push devs back towards that and away from nested server components and client IDs.  Webforms was a novel concept, but it created a lot of web-adverse architecture problems.